# Is it safe to use Server.Transfer() to transfer a request to a static image (.jpg, .png, etc)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a class which implements IHttpHandler that is designed to handle image resize requests. It handles Urls like so

```
http://mysite.com/imageHandler?image=myimg.jpg&width=100&height=100
```

Currently the handler looks for myimg.jpg on disk, cuts a 100x100 thumbnail (if it isn't already present) and redirects the client to the thumbnail like so

```
Response.RedirectPermanent("/some/virtualPath/to/thumbnail.jpg");
```

This has been working great, but I would like to avoid forcing the client to issue a second HTTP request. Is it safe to do the following?

```
Server.Transfer("/some/virtualPath/to/thumbnail.jpg")
```

All the [MSDN documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219294) talks about using Server.Transfer() to redirect to an aspx page, so I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do or not.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx) explicitly says:

> The page transferred to should be another .aspx page. For instance, a transfer to an .asp or .asmx page is not valid.

So, even if it *might* work, it's not "safe" in the sense that you can rely on this feature. You violate the [contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) by using a non-aspx page, so, theoretically, the method is allowed to behave arbitrarily.

A safe solution for your problem would be to send the thumbnail to the client using appropriate methods of the `Response` object, such as `BinaryWrite` (if the thumbnail image is in memory) or `TransmitFile` (if the image is on the disk). In that case, don't forget to set the HTTP header appropriately (`Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"`) to inform the client that this is a jpg image. The additional advantage of this method is that your thumbnail files no not need to reside in a publicly accessible directory of your web server.

Comment: Yeah, I stated that in my question. I'm looking for anecdotal evidence one way or the other, or suggestions for a different solution such as the newer HttpServerUtility.TransferRequest() method.

Comment: @twerq: Ok, I see. I wasn't sure since you linked to a KB article instead of the MSDN documentation. I've added suggestions for alternative solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this method was around when the question was originally written, but as of .NET 4.8, `Server.TransferRequest()` appears to be preferable for transferring static files.

See [HttpServerUtility.TransferRequest Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.transferrequest) on MSDN:

> This method is used when running with the integrated pipeline mode in IIS 7.0 to allow request processing to be transferred from one resource type to another while executing the target request with the correct request context. For example, you can use the TransferRequest method to transfer a request for an ASPX page to a request for an XML page.